# Transferring data from one np.array to another

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to transfer data from one numpy array to another whilst eliminating some of the data.  I think I can filter the data OK, but I am having trouble transferring it into another numpy array.  I created my second array with np.zeros, and I thought it was the right shape, but I get an error,

```
    onesd_prob_combinetest=np.zeros([star_number,1])
    for counter, value in enumerate(one_d_arrays):
         for index, element in enumerate(value):
             onesd_prob_combinetest[counter] = value[index]
             if sum(onesd_prob_combinetest) > 
                           sixty_eight_percenttest[counter]:
             break
```

The sixty_eight_percenttest is the following array [0.07326831 0.08325579 1.63425504 0.76375927].  I want to to values summing to the above 68 percent list into the new array.

I get this error message...

onesd_prob_combinetest[counter] = value[index]
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5295974) into shape (1)

I have been trying to do this for about 36 hours now, and just don't know how to do it.  I would be very grateful if someone could show me how.

I am not sure that this can even be done using numpy arrays.  I need some way of keeping the data in my rows apart from each other.

```
    Arrays are as follows  onesd_prob_combinetest:
    array([[0.],
          [0.],
          [0.],
          [0.]])
```

This next array appears odd maybe.  It was a 2D numpy array which I sliced into individual arrays thinking it would be easier to deal with.

```
    one_d_arrays
    [array([[0.0002739 , 0.00027299, 0.00027292, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        ]]), array([[0.00091127, 0.00090518, 0.00089081, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        ]]), array([[0.0012387 , 0.00123697, 0.0012369 , ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        ]]), array([[0.00141058, 0.00141006, 0.00141002, ..., 0.        , 0.        ,
    0.        ]])]
```

Comment: could you please add your input and expected output, that would help me validate

Comment: I have edited my post now.  I had to add the arrays into the section for code.  Thanks

Comment: what is star number in your input?

Comment: It is 4...so the onesd_prob_combinetest array is shape 4,1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution.

If I replace the numpy target array with a nested list, it seems to work!

I also changed the one_d-arrays back into it's original 2d array,rather than an array of arrays.

There is probably a much better way to do it, but I managed to get there.

Thank you so much for trying to help me.

If you have an alternative, please let me know.  Best wishes.

```
    onesd_prob_combinetest= [[] for _ in range(star_number)]

    for counter, value in enumerate(one_d_arrays):
        for index, element in enumerate(value):
            onesd_prob_combinetest[counter].append(element)
            if sum(onesd_prob_combinetest[counter]) > sixty_eight_percenttest[counter]:
                 break
```